# "Literally" insert string into HTML input

Tags: javascript, jquery, encoding

I want to insert a string "literally" into an HTML input field using jQuery.
The problem is that the string contains escaped characters and character codes, and all of those need to still be there when the string is inserted.
My problem seems to be with **escaped characters** (*thanks for the comments that pointed that out*). I can't figure out how I can insert the string without the escaped characters and codes being translated.

The literal strings come from a file `data.txt`. To clarify, this is just an exemplary string that is used to demonstrate that there can be escaped quotes and character codes etc. in the strings.

```
TEST\"/**\x3e
```

They are loaded (in node.js) from the file into an array of strings.

Wrapper code (Node.js) visits the page using the Chrome dev tools.
Here, for each string a script is prepared that is injected and executed on the page.
Therefore the `inputString` is inserted into the script, before it is injected.

So here is my problem with string escaping. I have the strings in literal format as data and I currently inject them as dynamically generated JavaScript code which is where escaping problems occur.

#### Injected Code

```js
// this was (currently incorrectly) injected into the page before 
// from the array of input strings that was loaded from data
let insertString = "TEST\"/**\x3e";  // <- 

let form = $("form").first();
let inputs = form.find(":input").not(":input[type=submit]");
let input = inputs.first();
input.focus().val(insertString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Exemplary form code on the page -->
<form action="post" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="input">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

#### What we got

[image: what we got]

#### What I want

[image: what we want]

The string is not inserted as is.
For example the character code `\x3e` is translated to `>`.
Also the escaped `\"` is translated to `"`.
It needs to be inserted just as it would be when copying and pasting from the data file.

---

#### Thoughts on a potential (manual) solution

So one potential solution is to rework the `data.txt` file and escape the strings correctly. So the first line might be `TEST\\\"/**\\x3e`, as @Jamiec and @Barmar have proposed.

```js
// injected before
let insertString = "TEST\\\"/**\\x3e";  // <- manually escaped

let form = $("form").first();
let inputs = form.find(":input").not(":input[type=submit]");
let input = inputs.first();
input.focus().val(insertString);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Exemplary form code on the page -->
<form action="post" method="post">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="input">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The string will then be inserted as intended, but the solution is still not satisfying, because it would be better for me to not touch the input data.
It would be best to have the input strings in the `data.txt` file exactly as they will look when they are inserted into the page.
This would require and additional step between loading the input data and inserting each string into the script (that is then injected into the page). Potentially this preprocessing can be done with regexp replacements.

Comment: You need to mask the backslash characters: `"TEST\\\"/**\\x3e"` jQuery doesn't matter, the problem is that you are storing the "short" version in `inputValue` already. Everything else is just a consequence of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape all the backslashes and quotes in the string. You can do this using a regular expression.

```js
function escape_string(string) {
  return string.replace(/[\\"']/g, "\\$&");
}

console.log('let str = "' + escape_string(prompt("Type a string")) + '";');
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how the escaping can be handled dynamically, e.g. I read `"TEST\"/**\x3e"` from file and escape it to `"TEST\\\"/**\\x3e"`?

Comment: Why would you need to do it dynamically? This is only necessary when you're typing the strings literally, not when you get the data dynamically.

Comment: To rephrase, is there a function that handles the escaping from `"TEST\"/**\x3e"` to `"TEST\\\"/**\\x3e"`?

Comment: Not as far as I know, there's not usually a need for it.

Comment: You can use a regexp: `str.replace(/[\\"']/g, "\\$&")`

Comment: @robinki That makes no sense. There's a function that takes a string with the content `TEST\"/**\x3e` and yields a string with the content `"TEST\\\"/**\\x3e"`, it's `JSON.stringify`. There is no function that takes a string with the content `"TEST\"/**\x3e"` (with quotes already?) and does what you want.

Comment: @Bergi Those strings are just an example. The problem is, I have strings in the exact form that they need to have when they are inserted into the input fields, e.g. `TEST\"/**\x3e` is the first line. What I'm trying to figure out is what is best to get the exact characters into the form input.

Comment: Where are you getting these strings from? If you're getting them dynamically, you don't need to do anything. Escaping is only an issue in string literals in program source code, not data.

Comment: @robinki Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65185681/edit) to tell us more about where those strings come from and how you insert them into script tag in your html files.

Comment: I have edited the question and stated where the strings come from and how they are processed. The problem is that they come from data, yes, but then they are inserted into a script which is injected as string into the page and executed. One option may be to escape each line of the input file, so each string is inserted correctly, but I want to find a more automated solution.

Comment: So you're generating JavaScript source code dynamically?

Comment: @Barmar, yes for this project I generate JS code dynamically and inject it into my page.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Loading from data and escaping the strings does the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with encoding, nor input fields - it is simply string escapes - so can be demonstrated using the console (or any other way of displaying a string).

In order to see the literal escape character `\` in a string you must escape the escape character with `\\` - see below:

```js
var text1 = "TEST\"/**\x3e";
console.log(text1)

var text2 = "TEST\\\"/**\\x3e";
console.log(text2)
```

As you can see the first output is your exact problem, where as the second escapes the escape character so you get what you expect in the output.